# How do I display the value of one cell in a cell on another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to build a spread sheet with multiple sheets.  The first sheet is the main 'working' page.  The additional sheets would be filters of data found on the first sheet.  On the first sheet on various rows (and various columns, though I could make the column standard) are listing of routines.  Similarly, on the first sheet are also listing of menus options, templates, etc.  What I want to do is create another sheet that just displays the routines in one column, the menu options in another, the templates in a 3rd etc.  I'd like this second sheet to be auto-maintained so that if someone adds/edits/deletes a routine, menu option, template on the first sheet it is automatically, added/edited/removed from the second sheet.  Is this possible?  What happens to cells on the first sheet if a user adds/edits/deletes information on the second sheet?

Thanks,
Fred

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most robust way to do this is to treat the data on the 1st tab as a database table.

Start by making the data into an Excel table as this helps a lot.

The easiest way to proceed from there is to use the Microsoft PowerQuery addin. This allows you to extract data from many sources & transform it on the fly. In this case you can use the 1st sheet table as the data source for your other sheets. Whenever the 1st sheet is updated, all you need to do is to refresh the data query (a single button) and all the other tables are updated. Those tables can be filtered as needed.

If someone changes one of the downstream tables, the change will be overridden when the data is next refreshed. Refreshing can be automated if required.